# Scikit-learn installed but not found,

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have already installed scipy, numpy and scikit-learn but when I'm on python shell I can't import sklearn, it says there's no module with that name:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in .../lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in .../site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in ...7/site-packages

>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's installed **for that interpreter**? Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? What OS/platform? How are you running the interpreter? How are you installing the libraries?

Comment: 1. No, how do I get sure of it?
2. Yes, I have 2.7 and 3.4
3. Os X 10.10
4. Typing python on the terminal
5. pip install ...

Comment: Probably the easiest way to be certain is to use a `virtualenv` - install `virtualenvhelper` then you can `mkvirtualenv`.